# streamz exception on dask gather

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, streaming, dask

i am trying to use streamz to manage an image processing pipeline.
I am simulating a camera using the class Camera and have set up the pipeline below.

```
import time
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray


class Camera(object):
    imgs = [imread(f + '.jpg') for f in ['1', '2', '3']]

    @staticmethod
    def grab_one():
        return Camera.imgs[int(time.time()) % 3]

def mc_streamz():
    from streamz import Stream
    def np2jpeg(np_im):
        from six import BytesIO
        from PIL import Image
        pim = Image.fromarray(np_im)
        io = BytesIO()
        pim.save(io,format='jpeg')
        io.seek(0)
        return io.read()

    def focusmetric(np_im):
        from skimage.filters import laplace
        return laplace(np_im).var()

    def asjpegframe(b_im):
        return b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + b_im + b'\r\n'

    from dask.distributed import Client
    client = Client()

    source = Stream()
    source.map(np2jpeg).map(asjpegframe).sink(print)
    source.scatter().map(rgb2gray).map(focusmetric).gather().sink(print)

    cam = Camera()

    for i in range(10):
        source.emit(cam.grab_one())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc_streamz()
```

However, when i run this i get the exception below when the gather() function is invoked and I cannot understand why. I hope someone can guide me on the right path, thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1438, in _gather
    exception = st.exception
AttributeError: exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/core.py", line 1255, in f
    result[0] = yield make_coro()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/core.py", line 322, in _
    result = yield self._emit(x)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/dask.py", line 98, in update
    f = yield self._emit(future)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/dask.py", line 123, in update
    result = yield client.gather(x, asynchronous=True)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1443, in _gather
    None)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: focusmetric-42e56666b87e375f3ece9246419ad199
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1438, in _gather
    exception = st.exception
AttributeError: exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "streamprocessing.py", line 83, in <module>
    mc_streamz()
  File "streamprocessing.py", line 51, in mc_streamz
    source.emit(cam.grab_one())
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/core.py", line 327, in emit
    sync(self.loop, _)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/core.py", line 1267, in sync
    six.reraise(*error[0])
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/core.py", line 1255, in f
    result[0] = yield make_coro()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/core.py", line 322, in _
    result = yield self._emit(x)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/dask.py", line 98, in update
    f = yield self._emit(future)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/projects/streamz/streamz/dask.py", line 123, in update
    result = yield client.gather(x, asynchronous=True)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1443, in _gather
    None)
  File "/Users/johndoe/anaconda3431/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: focusmetric-42e56666b87e375f3ece9246419ad199
```